# What is the weights field of a binomial glm object?

Tags: r, glm

I am looking over the code for a binomial glm in R, and I am stuck on what the weights field of the fitted model object means. As always, easier with a code example:

```
df <- read.table("testlogist.txt")
df
               Y                  X                  Z
#1   0.27704776536792913 0.23603334566204692  0.5557510873245723
#2   0.4324719071502214  0.34651701419196046  0.43710797460962514
#3   0.4167735154057556  0.3127069683360675   0.42471785049513144
#4   0.09145965948156985 0.00790928339056074  0.773223048457377
#5   0.6507341469057685  0.4886128300795012   0.2811902322857298
#6   0.5011218698377081  0.21096820215853596  0.20947237319807077
#7   0.8910596987670374  0.951916339835734    0.25137920979222494
#8   0.9497214110491393  0.9999046588986136   0.02037486871266725
#9   0.4729968024320567  0.25166218303197185  0.2877015122756894
#10  0.5942258380674803  0.9866663668987996   0.859512136087661

mod <- glm(y ~ 0 + x + z, df, family = binomial())
mod$weights
#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
#0.2468585 0.2465807 0.2470139 0.2332699 0.2244949 0.1635593 0.1936846 0.1501579 0.2279530 0.2361176
```

With a normal regression, weights are either NULL, or set by the caller as the `weights` argument to the GLM call, AFAIK. What is the interpretation of weights here, and how are they calculated?
Thanks!
(PS: I know the weights input argument has a special meaning for binomial regression, in that it means the frequency of observations. I am asking about the meaning of the internal field in the object. They may be related of course).

Comment: Did you read `?glm`? Because it provides a short description for what they are.

Comment: I'm a little worried about your data frame---you probably don't want it to have a column named `V1` where the entry on the first row is `y`. Could you post `str(df)` to make sure the data is imported correctly?

Comment: Looks like you might need the argument `header = TRUE` in `read.table`

Comment: Hi friends, thanks for the comments. 1) the data.frame, yes I copied it from my console, apparently from the first time where I missed the header=TRUE. I am sorry that this was confusing. I of course imported it correctly for the analysis.
2) Yes it holds "the weights in the final iteration of the IWLS fit". I am trying to understand what that means in statistical terms. Thanks!

Comment: I updated it to not confuse readers.